# React Native Android location request timed out

Tags: android, gps, react-native

In IOS there isn't a problem while looking for gps coords. It works fine.

On Android side its not stable as IOS. This problem both in real device and emulator. Sometimes it can find location, but sometimes not. Looking for 3days but there wasn't find a solution.

When my app cannot find my location, I tried via Google Maps app, it works like charm.

Here is my code for both IOS and Android;

```
getCurrentPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            this.setState({ initialPosition: position });
            alert(JSON.stringify(position))
            var coords = new Coords();
            coords.Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            coords.Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            this.getPharmaciesByCoordinates(coords);
        },
        (error) => alert(error.message),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        this.setState({ initialPosition: position });
    },
        (error) => alert(error.message),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );
}
```

Any kind of solution is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: This can help https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7495

Comment: I read this, there isn't working solution on this. Also thanks for you interest

Comment: Did you find any working solution for this. I am facing the same problem. I didn't find solution anywhere.

Comment: I fixed this problem, here is the component i created using a promise:
https://gist.github.com/a3diti/5466f7309752cbb2e63ecefff6365bb9
In android i removed maximumAge, i kept enableHighAccuracy to true, and added a permission check from RN PermissionsAndroid component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution via external lib that uses native `LocationManager`. It uses play services location and emitting location event as I want.

Here is the library;
https://bitbucket.org/timhagn/react-native-google-locations#readme

And when compiling for android, don't forget to include `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1" -> which version that you have write down here.
    ...
}
```

And finally don't forget to download `Google Play Services` and `Google Support Library` in **Android SDK Manager** you can find your play services versions into;

```
<android-sdk-location>/<sdk-version>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services
```

Answer (score 26):

I removed `maximumAge: 3600000` on Android and it working

Comment: Rremove maximumAge should be accepted answer to disable "Location request timed out" alert on Android.

Comment: Not getting the exact location can anyone facing the issue?

Answer (score 19):

It's possible that you are inside of the building or office and your signal is not that good. I've tried with many configuration and this one fit the best for me:

```
{
    enableHighAccuracy: false,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 10000
}
```

Or try increasing timeout. Because for me the usual 2000ms wasn't working, I kept getting "Location request timed out". So disable high accuracy, increase timeout and you're good to go.

Answer (score 8):

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
```

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
        console.log(initialPosition);
      },
      error => Alert.alert('Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},
    );
```

This function work for me and I have change the "AndroidManifest.xml" file with the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: This works. some low end devices takes time to get current position. so its best to increase timeout

Answer (score 6):

Hi I was facing same issue "request time out ".
 I have tried every possible solution which I found but, those could not work for me but recently I found one module which overcomes this problem.
     [react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service)
This worked for me .....

Answer (score 6):

For those who still facing the issue, be aware of the params. I used to leave params to defaults but when it comes to **enableHighAccuracy**, you should be careful because when you set this to false, that means you are requesting WIFI location else GPS location. If you don't set this true, you will probably receive error on emulators as I did.

> Supported options:
>
> **timeout (ms) -** Is a positive value representing the maximum length of time (in milliseconds) the device is allowed to take in order to return a position. Defaults to INFINITY.
>
> **maximumAge (ms) -** Is a positive value indicating the maximum age in milliseconds of a possible cached position that is acceptable to return. If set to 0, it means that the device cannot use a cached position and must attempt to retrieve the real current position. If set to Infinity the device will always return a cached position regardless of its age. Defaults to INFINITY.
>
> **enableHighAccuracy (bool) -** Is a boolean representing if to use GPS or not. If set to true, a GPS position will be requested. If set to false, a WIFI location will be requested.

[Detailed Documentation](https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation)

**Edit 1;**
I recommend you all to use this library instead of native one ([react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service)) as its created for such timeout issues.

Comment: This solution works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Remove Param 'maximumAge' & Just Keep

```
{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000}
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing **timeout** and **maximumAge** did solve the issue on android on my end

Answer (score 1):

I have done the app by location request. The command
`{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 25000, maximumAge: 3600000 },` will work on iOS but not in Android. I think you should check Platform.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (location) => {
            console.log('location ', location);
            if (this.validLocation(location.coords)) {
              this.locationToAddress(location.coords);
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log('request location error', error);
          },
          Platform.OS === 'android' ? {} : { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 10000  }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried various methods and npm modules. Finally I got solved this issue by using this module. I strongly suggest this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked fine after removing timeout and `maximumAge` and setting `enableHighAccuracy` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

**Working**
**{ enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 10000 },**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Add Permission in P list and android Manifest also**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 10000 },
      // { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to 2 ways to consider dealing with it:

1. Use [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) - a package that suppose to deal with that problem.
2. Try to call once with enableHighAccuracy=true and if it fails try to call it again with enableHighAccuracy=false.
   Details: It seems enableHighAccuracy=true try fetching the location via the GPS - when enableHighAccuracy=false the device first try fetching the location via Wifi and if it fails it try to fetch it via the GPS.

Here is how I've implemented number 2:

```
import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";

const getCurrentLocation = (resolve, enableHighAccuracy, onError) => {
    console.log(`[getCurrentPosition] enableHighAccuracy=${enableHighAccuracy.toString()}`);

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
            const location = {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
            }
            console.log('[getCurrentPosition] success');
            resolve(location);
        },
        onError,
        {enableHighAccuracy, timeout: 20000}
    );
};

/**
 * We first try to get location with enableHighAccuracy=true (try to get position via GPS) if it fails try to get it with enableHighAccuracy=false (try to get position from wifi)
 * @return {Promise}
 */
export const getCurrentPosition = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        getCurrentLocation(resolve, true,
            (error1) => {
                // failed to retrieve with enableHighAccuracy=true - now try with enableHighAccuracy=false
                console.log(`[getCurrentPosition] failed 1st time trying again with enableHighAccuracy=false, error: ${error1.message}`);

                getCurrentLocation(resolve, false, (error2) => {
                    // Could not retrieve location - we can live with that
                    console.log(`[getCurrentPosition] failed ${error2.message}`);
                    resolve();
                })
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i was stuck for 3 days but all in vain then
i just change timeout to value 20000ms.
now problem is resolved.

GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
enableHighAccuracy: true,
timeout: 20000,

just change/Increase  "timeout" value your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your android emulator GPS is enabled or not.

**Go to options ( "⋮" on emulator) --> Location --> Enable GPS signal should be enabled.**

[image: Options]

[image: Location]

[image: Enable GPS signal]

Answer (score -4):

the tricks is, if you set

```
{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 25000, maximumAge: 3600000 }
```

then it will work. full code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class GeolocationExample extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
  error: null,
};
}

componentDidMount() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
       });
       },
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 25000, maximumAge: 3600000 },
);}

 render() {
return (
  <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
    <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
    {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
  </View>
  );
 }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```

Comment: How do you think it will give correct current location and not something from cache?

Comment: question is regarding request timeout so if you set maximumAge & timeout to a higher number it may not get real-time data but from the cache