# React Native GeoLocation is not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native

Can anyone confirm if React Native Geolocation is actually working on Android?
I am stuck with location request timed out while using `getCurrentPosition()` method and no error message while using `watchPosition()` method.

I have added the required permission (FINE LOCATION) on AndroidManifest.xml and location permission is allowed for the app.

Here is my implementation:

```
componentWillMount() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log('+++++++');
        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
        this.setState({
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);

      },

    );
}
```

React Native Version : 0.42

Answer (score 2):

you need to change enableHighAccuracy to false

```
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO; 

this.state = {
        region:{}}

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    console.log(position);
                    this.setState({
                        region: {
                            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
                        }
                    });
                },
                (error) => console.log(new Date(), error),
                {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 3000}
            );
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: This is not suported anymore by react

Comment: I approve `enableHighAccuracy: false` it's still working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After implementing all above answers 
i had to **restart my new phone then it started working**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, location works perfectly in our React Native apps for Android.

First of all, `getCurrentPosition(..)` does not return a watchId. You should be using `watchPosition(..)` for that. Check that your device has location services enabled and if you're testing it in the emulator, that you've set a location in emulator settings. Another note: on Android M and higher, you also need to request permissions using the  `PermissionsAndroid.check(...)` and `PermissionsAndroid.request(...)` API calls.

Comment: sorry. watchId was a blunder. I just updated code. I am running the app on a real device. I am using `react-native-permissions` for handling the permission issue. Location Service is enabled.

I have already granted location permission for the app manually for test. @david-xu

Comment: Can you provide snippets of the code working for you ? @david-xu

Comment: This guided me https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referring to the `position` object, just deal with the `coords` object.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      ({coords}) => {
        const {latitude, longitude} = coords
        this.setState({
          position: {
            latitude,
            longitude,
          },
          region: {
            latitude,
            longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.001,
            longitudeDelta: 0.001,
          }
        })
      },
      (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
      // 'enableHighAccuracy' sometimes causes problems
      // If it does, just remove it.
      {enableHighAccuracy: true} 
    )
```

Comment: not working. I don't know how but from yesterday, it started working on my device but not yet working on my colleague's device. damn

Comment: Did you try eliminating `{enableHighAccuracy: true}`?

Comment: Also, are you using the same Google Maps API key? That might be causing problems.

Comment: I am not using maps at all. I am stuck with getting longitude and latitude right now. Yes I trued eliminating {enableHighAccuracy: true}

Comment: What happens if you adjust your location settings in the android device from high accuracy to low accuracy?

Comment: With enableHighAccuracy=false, it worked on another device of my friend but not mine. Everything going over my head.

Comment: So, what happens if you adjust the **local** android settings to low accuracy? Like: `Settings>location>locating method>GPS only`

Comment: Same. Not working. May be. There is problem with my device. Thanks for replying. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this because I was in a building which resulted to my device not being able to properly capture the gps signals. If you are in a closed building, try moving outside.

Answer (score 0):

My advise to get perfect location data is to create 2 location handlers.

I use [react-native-location](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location) as a first handler,

if location cant be fetched, we use the second handler using native geolocation.

Never fails, Compability:

- IOS - all versions
- ANDROID - all above SDK 20

Check the example below:

> Configuration

```
RNLocation.configure({
     distanceFilter: 0.5,
     desiredAccuracy: {
         ios: "best",
         android: "highAccuracy"
     },
     headingOrientation: "portrait",
     // Android ONLY
     androidProvider: "auto",
     interval: 5000, // Milliseconds
     fastestInterval: 10000, // Milliseconds
     maxWaitTime: 5000, // Milliseconds
     // IOS ONLY
     allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates: false,
     headingFilter: 1, // Degrees
     pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically: false,
     showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: false,
})
```

> Function **getUserLocation**

```
static getUserLocation = async () => {
    let locationSubscription: any = null
    let locationTimeout: any = null
    const options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 25000 }
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        // request permissions using RN Location
        RNLocation.requestPermission({
            ios: "whenInUse",
            android: {
              detail: "fine"
            }
        }).then(granted => {
            console.log("Location Permissions: ", granted)
            // if has permissions try to obtain location with RN location
            if (granted) {
                locationSubscription && locationSubscription()
                locationSubscription = RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates(([locations]: any) => {
                    locationSubscription()
                    locationTimeout && clearTimeout(locationTimeout)
                    console.log("location fetched with RN Geolocation")
                    resolve({ coords: { latitude: locations.latitude, longitude: locations.longitude }})
                })
            } else {
                locationSubscription && locationSubscription()
                locationTimeout && clearTimeout(locationTimeout)
                console.log("no permissions to obtain location")
                resolve(null)
            }

            // if RN Location cant resolve the request use Native Location instead
            locationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((locations) => {
                    locationSubscription()
                    locationTimeout && clearTimeout(locationTimeout)
                    console.log("location fetched with Native Geolocation")
                    resolve(locations)
                }, error => {
                    locationSubscription && locationSubscription()
                    locationTimeout && clearTimeout(locationTimeout)
                    console.log("location error", error)
                    resolve(null)
                }, options);
            }, 15000)
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cd android
gradlew clean

dependencies
    "react-native": "0.62.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",

Answer (score -2):

Better if you try this code, I have tested in Android OS 8, RN 0.49.5
[React Native current location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47282465/1429832)
the trick is to set

`{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 25000, maximumAge: 3600000 }`

Comment: well, now it doesn't work on android RN 0.55.4, react 16.4,