# Why does geolocation not working on Android Emulator with React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I'm trying to get the current user location in Android with React Native. I have written the following snippet in the App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    location: null
  };

  findCoordinates = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const location = JSON.stringify(position);

        this.setState({ location });
      },
      error => alert(error.message),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    );

    alert("SKIPPED");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.findCoordinates}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>Find My Coords?</Text>
          <Text>Location: {this.state.location}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ... some style ...
});
```

Since I use an Android emulator, I have also added the following line in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file located in `android\app\src\main`, just above the `application` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

When I run it, no request for sharing the GPS location pops up and also the `getCurrentPosition` function seems to be just skipped. The state is not updated, no error is displayed and the alert "SKIPPED" appears.

That is what I see on the screen after the "SKIPPED" alert is dismissed:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to restart my emulator and then it started working correctly. Found a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732816/react-native-geolocation-is-not-working-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

### IOS

If you are using Simulator for iOS, go to Simulator’s menu bar and select Debug ‣ Location ‣ Custom Location. Enter A Coord for latitude and longitude.

### Android

If you are using an Android virtual device, click the three dots, representing Extended controls, on the toolbar in the emulator. In the Location section, Enter A Coord for latitude and longitude.

Comment: Coords are already set up in my emulator. Please, look at my edit.